# Having problems with multiple schemas when unit testing a database

Tags: java, hsqldb, dbunit

I'm using HypserSQL DB and DBUnit for unit testing. Unfortunately, my app connects to multiple schemas(cannot change that). Whenever schema name comes into play, I get org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException

When I use 'CREATE SCHEMA' in my databaseSchema.sql, the dataset seems to be inserted just fine; however, when my DAO tries to pull something that refers to my schema, I get the exception.

When I use 'CREATE USER' in my databaseSchema.sql, the exception is thrown when loading dataset.

Relevant pieces of my test class

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    IDatabaseConnection iDBConn = getConnection();

    //Enable
    String qualifiedTableNames = "http://www.dbunit.org/features/qualifiedTableNames";
    iDBConn.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);

    initSchema();
    insertDataSet(iDBConn);
    target = new OracleDAO(jdbcConnection, null);
}

protected IDatabaseConnection getConnection() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:fdr", "sa", "");

    return new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);
}

protected void initSchema() throws Exception {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/databaseSchema.sql").getFile()));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (br.ready()) {
        sb.append(br.readLine());
    }

    Statement stmt = jdbcConnection.createStatement() ; 
    String[] queries = sb.toString().split(";");
    for (String query : queries) {
        stmt.execute(query);
    }
}

protected IDataSet insertDataSet(IDatabaseConnection iDBConn) throws Exception {
    loadedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dataset.xml"));
    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(iDBConn, loadedDataSet);
    return loadedDataSet;
}
```

databaseSchema.sql

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;

CREATE SCHEMA SCHEMA_A;
--Also tried CREATE USER SCHEMA_A pwd;

CREATE TABLE if not exists SCHEMA_A.TBL_1
(   "ID" NUMBER, 
    "OTHER_ID" NUMBER(10,0)
);
```

dataset.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>      
    <SCHEMA_A.TBL_1 ID="1" other_id="1" />
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating maven dependency for dbUnit fixed this issue. Now I can work with multiple schemas.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```